# change border-style in :hover state in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have problem with apply border-style change in Firefox.
My code:

```
.wizardCircle{
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 45px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 45px;
    border: 3px solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center; 
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
#wizardRow>div:hover .wizardCircle{
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

The problem exist only in FF. I tried to use `border: 3px dotted` insted `border-style` and also `!important` but this also not working. CSS `transform` working in all browsers.
HTML structure:

```
  <div id="wizardRow" class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-2 wizardCompleted">
          <a href="#"><span class="wizardCircle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="wizardDesc">Tekst</span></a>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle of your code please

Comment: Seems fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/yRBCm/

Comment: here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/5fbyU/

Comment: if I add colour, then just colour will change, border remian solid

Comment: i think it bcos of border radius remove it and check it and use border:3px solid #000

Comment: exactly if I remove `border-radius` its working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that as it's an open bug in Firefox:

[Bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721)

If you remove the `border-radius` it will work proper.

Answer (score 3):

Your `border-radius` makes that the dotted border disappear.

You can see better on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jSBLY/).

```
#wizardRow>div:hover .wizardCircle{
    ...
    border-radius: 25%;
    ....
}
```

If you put an small value, it will be possible to see the changes happening.

Actually this happen because your circle is all **radius**, when you say that your box will have `border-radius: 50%`, you're saying that each corner will take 50% of the border. Then there's no remaining space to the **border** be displayed. So what is happening is that the **border-style** property doesn't affect the **border-radius** space.

The reason for that is a bug in the way that Firefox render the `border-radius` property.

Comment: Yup, it's a bug on Firefox, but it happens for a reason, and it's described above.